# Root is receiving "operation not permitted" error when trying to move a a users .bash_profile

Tags: files, permissions, rhel

This are the permissions on the RHEL5 machine:

```
[root@server1 belmin]# ls -la | egrep '\.(bash_profile)?$'
drwx------   9 belmin belmin     4096 Sep 16 14:29 .
drwxr-xr-x  40 root   root       4096 Sep  2 15:32 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 belmin belmin      801 Aug 25  2011 .bash_profile
```

However I am receiving an error when doing a `mv` operation:

```
[root@server1 belmin]# mv .bash_profile{,.backup-20140916}
mv: cannot move `.bash_profile' to `.bash_profile.backup-20140916': Operation not permitted
```

Saw [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/595813/write-file-permissions-for-root-user) but that's about an `NFS` mount, this is an `ext3` mount:

```
[root@server1 belmin]# df -P .
Filesystem         1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/sda3             28794584   7901184  19430684      29% /

[root@server1 belmin]# mount | grep sda3
/dev/sda3 on / type ext3 (rw)
```

Selinux is enabled but I do not see any relevant audit message in syslog.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Immutable flag set? `lsattr | egrep '\.(bash_profile)?$'`

Comment: Feel silly now. Had to do `lsattr -a` but yup. Can you please post as answer so I could accept? Maybe it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check if immutable flag is set on `.bash_profile`:

```
lsattr .bash_profile
```

You can remove it with:

```
chattr -i .bash_profile
```

HTH, Cheers